# class initialisation issue when passing argument

Tags: c++, qt, class

I do have an issue when using a class.

I do have a main file defined as below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    uint32_t error;

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QPalette pal = app.palette();
    pal.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::white);
    app.setPalette(pal);

    // Detecting puls device
    mtp_wrapper *MyDevice = new mtp_wrapper;
    error = MyDevice->ConnectDevice();

    if(error != ERROR_NONE) {
        app.quit();
    }
    else {

        MyDevice->Properties();
        MyDevice->DeviceScan();

        app.setOrganizationName("i.am+");
        app.setApplicationName("PULS");
        MainWindow MyMainWindow(MyDevice);
        MyMainWindow->show();
        return app.exec();
    }
}
```

My issue is MainWindow MyMainWindow(MyDevice); which seems to not be correctly initialised.

The class mtp_wrapper is defined as below:

```
mtp_wrapper::mtp_wrapper() : DeviceMngr(NULL)
{
     LIBMTP_Init();
     DeviceMngr = new Device_struct;
     DeviceMngr->deviceConnected = false;
}
```

Device_struct is a struct which contain a list of variables which defined the device.

In order to use this information in the mainWindow program (which is my user interface part), I have defined the MainWindow as below:

Mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(mtp_wrapper& device);

private:
    /* Mtp device access */
    mtp_wrapper& m_device;
...
}
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(mtp_wrapper& device) :
    m_device(device)
{
    resize(800,600);
    setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(true);
    /* Creation of the Top bar section */
...
}
```

error I have is no matching contructor for init mainwindow.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem caused by passing the pointer `mtp_wrapper *MyDevice` to the constructor that accepts a reference - `MainWindow(mtp_wrapper &)`. You can solve it by changing either constructor, or the way how you pass the argument or replace the pointer with the value. I would do the following (the third option):

```
mtp_wrapper MyDevice;
error = MyDevice.ConnectDevice();

if(error != ERROR_NONE) {
    app.quit();
}
else {
    [..]
    MainWindow MyMainWindow(MyDevice);
    [..]     
}
```